# Limit number of results of a SPARQL query within a range

Tags: sparql

Suppose that we have the following triples:

```
:Influenza :hasSymptom :Fever
:Influenza :hasSymptom :Headache
:Influenza :hasSymptom :SoreThroat
:Influenza :minQuantityOfSymptoms 1
:Influenza :maxQuantityOfSymptoms 3
```

I want to develop a SPARQL query that returns a number of solutions within the **minQuantityOfSymptoms** and **maxQuantityOfSymptoms**.

I achieved a similar result by using the LIMIT modifier, however I have to explicity declare the upper bound, so that way there is no randomness. The following query uses the LIMIT modifier and return always two symptoms:

```
SELECT ?symptom WHERE {
    :Influenza :hasSymptom ?symptom .
} LIMIT 2
```

I appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after? In the above example, you have properties `:minQuantityOfSymptoms` and `:maxQuantityOfSymptoms` defined in your data as 1 and 3, respectively. The data also shows that the _actual_ number of symptoms is 3 (since there are 3 symptoms defined). Yet in your example query you set the limit to 2. So where does the number 2 come from, or more specifically: where do you _expect_ the number of results the query should return to come from?

Comment: Put another way: assuming your data is actually always correct, simply returning all symptoms without a LIMIT will satisfy your constraint - it would return 3 symptoms, which is in the specified range. So why isn't that satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select *some* symptoms of a disease, and you want to select at least *minQuantity* and less than *maxQuantity*.  That would explain in your case where min is 1 and max is 3, you've selected 2 (= 3 − 1) symptoms.  You can do that in SPARQL, though it's not super pretty.  First, let's get some loadable data:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:Influenza :hasSymptom :Fever .
:Influenza :hasSymptom :Headache .
:Influenza :hasSymptom :SoreThroat .
:Influenza :minQuantityOfSymptoms 1 .
:Influenza :maxQuantityOfSymptoms 3 .
```

Now, the trick will be to impose an ordering on the symptoms for each disease so that you can associate an index with each one.  Then you can take just the symptoms that have an index less than max-min:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?disease ?symptom where {
  ?disease :minQuantityOfSymptoms ?min ;
           :maxQuantityOfSymptoms ?max ;
           :hasSymptom ?symptom, ?symptom_ .
  filter ( str(?symptom_) <= str(?symptom) )
}
group by ?disease ?symptom ?max ?min
having (count(?symptom_) <= (?max-?min))
```

```
--------------------------
| disease    | symptom   |
==========================
| :Influenza | :Headache |
| :Influenza | :Fever    |
--------------------------
```